# JQuery: stop synchronizing inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to synchronize input fields when a radio button is checked using

```js
$("#input1").on("input", function() {
   $("#input2").prop('value', this.value);
});
```

However, when the radio button is unchecked, the synchronization continues.

How can you stop the synchronization when the condition isn't met anymore?

I've created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user20556/5tg8qf96/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#foobar input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    switch ($(this).val()) {
      case 'cubic':
        $("#metricavalue").prop("readonly", false);
        $("#metricbvalue").prop("readonly", true);
        $("#metriccvalue").prop("readonly", true);

        $("#metricavalue").css({
          'background-color': '#FFFFFF'
        });
        $("#metricbvalue").css({
          'background-color': '#DCDCDC'
        });
        $("#metriccvalue").css({
          'background-color': '#DCDCDC'
        });

        $("#metricbvalue").prop("value", $("#metricavalue").val());
        $("#metriccvalue").prop("value", $("#metricavalue").val());

        $("#metricavalue").on("input", function() {
          $("#metricbvalue").prop('value', this.value);
          $("#metriccvalue").prop('value', this.value);
        });
        break;
      case 'hexagonal':
        $("#metricavalue").prop("readonly", false);
        $("#metricbvalue").prop("readonly", true);
        $("#metriccvalue").prop("readonly", false);

        $("#metricavalue").css({
          'background-color': '#FFFFFF'
        });
        $("#metricbvalue").css({
          'background-color': '#DCDCDC'
        });
        $("#metriccvalue").css({
          'background-color': '#FFFFFF'
        });

        $("#metricavalue").on("input", function() {
          $("#metricbvalue").prop('value', this.value);
        });
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="foobar">
  <input type="radio" name="crystalsystem" id="cubic" value="cubic">
  cubic <br />

  <input type="radio" name="crystalsystem" id="hexagonal" value="hexagonal">
  hexagonal
</fieldset>


<p>&nbsp;</p>

<i>a</i> value:
<input type="number" name="metrica" id="metricavalue"><br />

<i>b</i> value:
<input type="number" name="metricb" id="metricbvalue"><br />

<i>c</i> value:
<input type="number" name="metricc" id="metriccvalue">
```

- Select cubic, provide a numerical value for 'a': b and c will be synchronized with 'a'.
- Select hexagonal, change 'a', and 'c' will still be synchronized with 'a'.

How can you stop 'c' being dependent on 'a'?

Comment: simply by use `.off('input')` .. `$("#metricavalue").off('input').on("input"........`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you need to use [`off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/)<sup>*1</sup> with [`input` event](https://api.jquery.com/off/#off-event)<sup>*2</sup> in order to stop this behavior

*1

> The `.off()` method removes event handlers that were attached with
>   `.on().` See the discussion of delegated and directly bound events on
>   that page for more information. Calling `.off()` with no arguments
>   removes all handlers attached to the elements. Specific event handlers
>   can be removed on elements by providing combinations of event names,
>   namespaces, selectors, or handler function names. When multiple
>   filtering arguments are given, all of the arguments provided must
>   match for the event handler to be removed.

*2

> .off(event)

here is the snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#foobar input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    switch ($(this).val()) {
      case 'cubic': $("#metricavalue").prop("readonly", false);
      $("#metricbvalue").prop("readonly", true);
      $("#metriccvalue").prop("readonly", true);
      $("#metricavalue").css( {
        'background-color': '#FFFFFF'
      }
      );
      $("#metricbvalue").css( {
        'background-color': '#DCDCDC'
      }
      );
      $("#metriccvalue").css( {
        'background-color': '#DCDCDC'
      }
      );
      $("#metricbvalue").prop("value", $("#metricavalue").val());
      $("#metriccvalue").prop("value", $("#metricavalue").val());
      $("#metricavalue").on("input", function() {
        $("#metricbvalue").prop('value', this.value);
        $("#metriccvalue").prop('value', this.value);
      }
      );
      break;
      case 'hexagonal' : $("#metricavalue").prop("readonly", false);
      $("#metricbvalue").prop("readonly", true);
      $("#metriccvalue").prop("readonly", false);
      $("#metricavalue").css( {
        'background-color': '#FFFFFF'
      }
      );
      $("#metricbvalue").css( {
        'background-color': '#DCDCDC'
      }
      );
      $("#metriccvalue").css( {
        'background-color': '#FFFFFF'
      }
      );
      $("#metricavalue").off('input').on("input", function() {
        $("#metricbvalue").prop('value', this.value);
      }
      );
      break;
    }
  }
  );
}

);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="foobar">
  <input type="radio" name="crystalsystem" id="cubic" value="cubic"> cubic <br />

  <input type="radio" name="crystalsystem" id="hexagonal" value="hexagonal"> hexagonal
</fieldset>


<p>&nbsp;</p>

<i>a</i> value:
<input type="number" name="metrica" id="metricavalue"><br />

<i>b</i> value:
<input type="number" name="metricb" id="metricbvalue"><br />

<i>c</i> value:
<input type="number" name="metricc" id="metriccvalue">
```